# How to have the same execution id in logs on Cloud Functions for Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

There's multiple executions happening interleaved/concurrently in firebase. The log id changes when new execution happens and the old execution id is forgotten. So the execution id moves forward only. When the old function resumes, it uses new execution id. Is there a way to achieve old execution id for old function & new execution id for new function.

[image: firebase logs]

**Workflow**:
Lets say Function1 & Function2 are diffrent triggers of same function.
1. Function1 does some db reads and do http requests. This returns an http promise - This takes some time(maybe some ms). Lets assume its execution-id from log is `154690519665944`.
2. Function2 get triggered while function1 was waiting. function2 gets execution-id `154690574405903`. function2 also does same thing and waits for http response.
3. Function1 resumes and it got http response and while logging it uses another execution-id `154694739233261` in log.

What happened to execution-id `154690519665944` ?

Since there's multiple triggers happening simultaneously, the only way to find whether a function completed successfully is to check logs. So by using execution-id as the filter, I could have find whether the function executed successfully or not. But because firebase changes execution-id randomly, I guess I have to find another solution.

PS: There's an update call  which will trigger the same function. Does that change the parent function execution-id ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking. Each execution of a function will get its own execution ID, which is maintained for as long as that function is executing.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code or complete logs, I don't think a definitive answer can be provided.

However, it sounds like the question you're asking is how can you keep data in memory across asynchronous transactions.  Regardless of Firebase or not, you basically have two options:

1. commit that data to the database during the first part of the
   transaction and then retrieve it in the second part
2. pass the data
   from the first part to the second part so that it already has it.

You seem to be relying on the execution-id, so I would recommend taking the latter approach and passing that id along as part the input to your httprequest and having the server your calling return it in its response.

Comment: Yes, use a DB. [This link](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec#stateless_functions) says "If you need to share state across function invocations, your function should use a service such as Cloud Datastore, Cloud Firestore or Cloud Storage to persist data."